# Object Interaction n Java

Tags: java, object

I'm making a pokemon game for fun and I want to be able to reduce the HP of the two pokemon fighting. What i'm doing is calling a method inside an 'if statement',which is inside of a loop, an have Java call a method from another class to reduce the HP.

Below is the Code as I have it...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gameTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner inputSystem = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner playerName = inputSystem;


        System.out.println("Hello Player please type in the name of your pokemon.");

        pokemon playerOne = new pokemon(playerName.nextLine());
        pokemon playerTwo = new pokemon();

        System.out.println(playerOne.toString());//shows player pokemon
        System.out.println(playerTwo.toString());//shows enemy pokemon

        System.out.println("Let's Battle! What do you do?");

        while (playerOne.getHealthPoints() >= 0 || playerTwo.getHealthPoints() >= 0){
        System.out.println("1. Bite 2. Slash 3. Flee");
        int userChoice = inputSystem.nextInt();
            if (userChoice == 3){
            break;
            }
            else if (userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2){
                //playerTwo.getHealthPoints() 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also like I said above i'm calling a method from another class..

```
public class pokemon {

    private String pokemonSpecies;
    private String nameOfpokemon;
    private int attackDamage;
    private int healthPoints;

    public pokemon (){
        nameOfpokemon = "Enemy";
        attackDamage = 1;
        healthPoints = 3;
    }
    public pokemon (String desiredName){
        nameOfpokemon = desiredName;
        attackDamage = 1;
        healthPoints = 3;
    }
    public String getPokemonSpecies() {
        return pokemonSpecies;
    }
    public void setPokemonSpecies(String pokemonSpecies) {
        this.pokemonSpecies = pokemonSpecies;
    }
    public String getNameOfpokemon() {
        return nameOfpokemon;
    }
    public void setNameOfpokemon(String nameOfpokemon) {
        this.nameOfpokemon = nameOfpokemon;
    }
    public int getAttackDamage() {
        return attackDamage;
    }
    public void setAttackDamage(int attackDamage) {
        this.attackDamage = attackDamage;
    }
    public int getHealthPoints() {
        return healthPoints;
    }
    public void setHealthPoints() {
        this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name of Pokemon: " + nameOfpokemon + " Attack Damage: " + attackDamage + " Health Points: " + healthPoints;
    }
    public int enemyDamage(int damage){
        setHealthPoints() = getAttackDamage() - getHealthPoints();
    }
}
```

The last bit about public in `enemyDamage(...)` is where I'm stuck. I don't know if I should send an integer that can reduce the HP. Or is I should use this method to call other methods...

Any advice?

Comment: The line inside the method 'enemyDamage' is probably not valid Java. 
Think about what you want to happen; 'this needs to TAKE damage' and so on.

Comment: change `setHealthPoints() = getAttackDamage() - getHealthPoints()` to `setHealthPoints(getHealthPoints() - getAttackDamage())` and change the signature of the setter. A setter has to receive a parameter to do anything sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use can change your `setHealthPoints()` method to

```
public void setHealthPoints(int healthPoints) {
    this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
}
```

Here I assume

> damage = attack/damage done by opponent's pokemon.
>
> getHealthPoints() = my pokemon's health.

Then `enemyDamage()` goes in this way.

```
public void enemyDamage(int damage){
    setHealthPoints(getHealthPoints() - damage);
}
```

Comment: With the second method what do you return? Do you return the 'damage' or something else?

Comment: Updated! Thanks. Actually it should not return anything as it only set health points after the damage. You can get the health by `getHealthPoints()`

Comment: Seems to work but the damage is saving on to the pokemons healhpoints field.

Comment: Damage is not saving. Damage will be subtracted from the Initial health of the pokemon by using the method `enemyDamage()`.

Comment: Got it working. public void enemyLosses(){
  System.out.println(getNameOfpokemon() + " has fallen and can't get up. It's over and you win!");
 } // THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Happy Coding! Mark it as the correct answer if it satisfies the answer.